# glht and emmeans returning crazy compact letters for unbalanced dataset in R

Tags: r, statistics, posthoc, emmeans

**Hi**

I am having a problem when trying to get glht or emmeans to define compact letters for a dataset with unequal sample size. When using glht or emmeans i get these crazy compact letters. What am I doing wrong? Could it be because of unequal variance?

**Model**

```
> Musling.BoxKonc <- aov(BoxHg2 ~ Station, data = Musling)
```

[image: Q-Q-plot]
[image: Residualplot]
[image: Graph]
**glht**

```
> BoxMusling.Tukey <- glht(Musling.BoxKonc, linfct = mcp(Station = "Tukey"))
> cld(BoxMusling.Tukey, alpha = .05, Letters = letters)
      1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8      10      11      12      13      15 
   "ac"   "bcd"    "ef"   "bcd"    "fg"   "bdf"     "a" "bcdeg"   "ade"    "ab"  "adeg"     "g"   "deg"
```

**emmeans**

```
> interBoxMusling <- emmeans(Musling.BoxKonc, "Station")
> cld(interBoxMusling, Letter = letters)
 Station emmean    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL .group  
 7         6.87 0.167 141     6.54     7.20  a      
 11        7.28 0.536 141     6.22     8.34  abc    
 1         7.58 0.240 141     7.10     8.05  ab     
 4         7.89 0.225 141     7.44     8.33   bcd   
 10        8.08 0.351 141     7.38     8.77  abcde  
 2         8.14 0.219 141     7.71     8.58   bcd   
 6         8.76 0.240 141     8.28     9.23    cdef 
 12        8.86 0.657 141     7.56    10.16  abcdefg
 8         9.15 0.657 141     7.85    10.45  abcdefg
 3         9.28 0.225 141     8.84     9.73      ef 
 5         9.80 0.232 141     9.34    10.26       fg
 13       10.77 0.294 141    10.19    11.36        g
 15       10.99 0.929 141     9.15    12.82     defg

Confidence level used: 0.95 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 13 estimates 
significance level used: alpha = 0.05
```

Comment: So why do you think these results are crazy? Some means have much lower SEs than others, and the higher the SE, the harder it is to distinguish from other means.

Comment: @RussLenth because the grouping of significans doesn't match the graphical representation of the data. Is it normal to get significans grouping like: "abcdefg"?

Comment: Yes. Stations 12 and 8 are not statistically different from any other station, based on Tukey-adjusted P values. Both of those stations have huge SEs

Comment: @RussLenth When looking at the graph there should be significant difference between for example station 12 og 15 [link](https://imgur.com/a/aipMNbN)

Comment: Look at the t tests, with Tukey-adjusted P values

Comment: I'm not sure which graph you mean, but none of the ones you show allow one to judge the significance of differences. If you do `pwpm(interBoxMusling)`, that will show a matrix with all the adjusted P values, including the one comparing stations 12 and 15. I actually recommend against CLDs because they are based on a hard line for significance and because they display NON-findings rather than findings. They can also be confusing, especially with wildly unequal SEs for comparing means, as your example illustrates.

Comment: I have expanded on the above comments and they are included in the answer I posted.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, just to make sure everyone is on the same page, compact letter displays (CLDs) are constructed in such a way that two means that share the same letter are *not* "significantly different" from one another at the stated significance level.

In a nice balanced situation with homogeneous error variance (that is, the SE of each comparison is the same), then, no matter what, all of the groups will be cohesive, in the sense that if two means share a grouping letter, all means between them share the same grouping letter. However, in the case where the SEs for comparing two means are not all the same, then there can be gaps in the groupings; and when there are huge disparities among those SEs compared with the differences among the means, such gaps are almost certain to occur, leading to what may be regarded as "crazy" compact letter displays.

To understand the specifics in what we see here, first note that in this simple model, the fitted values are exactly the same as the estimated marginal means (EMMs); thus, the vertical stacks of points in the residuals-versus-fitted plot appear in exactly the same order, left-to-right, as the top-to-bottom order of the `cld(interBoxMusling)` call. This makes it easy to identify what is going on with each entry. For example, the leftmost stack of points in the plot corresponds to station 7, whose EMM is 6.87, and for which there is quite a bit of data. Note also that Station 7 has only one grouping letter, `a`, so it is grouped with stations 11, 1, 10, 12, and 8, but statistically different from the other stations. There are gaps in the `a` grouping, the first one occurring with station 4 (4th from the left in the plot) which has an EMM of 7.89; there is quite a bit of data on that station as well as station 7, so those two stations are significantly different and hence *not* in the same group.

But what about stations 12 and 8, which are quite a ways down the line, and the two EMMs to either side of the "9" tick mark in the plot? They are also in group `a`. In the plot, observe that there are only 2 observations in each of those stations. That makes it hard for those stations to differ significantly from other means -- there just isn't much data to indicate there'd be a difference, and statistical significance, above all, has to do with whether there is evidence (data) to conclude a difference. In fact, due to the small sample sizes and that those two stations are midway in the list of means, they do not differ statistically from *any* other station -- they share every single grouping letter.

The largest mean belongs to station 15,and there is just one observation for that station (note that the SE of that mean is greater than any other). But because it is the largest EMM, it still differs significantly from some of the others, and does not share grouping letters `a`, `b`, or `c`.

In general, if you look at the means with the most grouping letters, those tend to be the ones with the smallest sample sizes, and vice versa.

It is the disparities in sample sizes that make the CLD look "crazy." I suggest that this is an example showing how CLDs can be confusing and that is one of several undesirable qualities of them. The others I would mention are:

- CLDS rely on a hard cutoff in P values, in this case 0.05, whereas some other ways of displaying P values allow for a gray area in judging significance.
- CLDs highlight *non*-findings rather than findings. Two means being not statistically different is not a finding, it is a situation where we can't say anything definitive. And that's really why the CLD looks crazy in a situation like this. Grouping letters make it appear that those means belong together, when in fact they simply fail to not belong together.

Another somewhat unrelated point: the craziness of the CLD in this example has nothing to do with unequal variances. That is because the results displayed depend only on the model that was fitted to the data, and the `aov()` model presumes that all observations have the same variance. This is notable again in stations 12 and 8, which each have two observations, but they are quite close together in station 8 and farther apart in station 12. The table results show the same SE for both EMMs, and that's because they have the same sample size. Had we used a model that allowed different variances, then those SEs would have been different. The CLD display would have been different too: still crazy, but crazy in a different way.

By the way, the bar graph shown is unsuitable for this analysis for exactly the above reasons, that it estimates a different variance for each station. Note that the error bars for stations 8 and 12 are very different, even though the tabled SEs are the same. (And note there is no error bar at all for station 15, because there is only one observation and thus no error-variance estimate.) When presenting analyses, it is important for all of the results displayed are based on the same model, unless it is clearly stated that different models are being considered.

The **emmeans** package does offer other ways of displaying pairwise comparisons reasonably compactly. Two to consider here are `pwpp()` (pairwise P-value plot), which shows P values graphically, and `pwpm()`, which shows them in matrix form. And of course, the `pairs()` or `summary()` functions are available for a detailed, less compact presentation. The `plot()` function has a `comparisons` option that displays "comparison arrows", but it doesn't always work and almost certainly would fail with this example.

Comment: I may come back and add a bounty to reward this answer (can't do it for another day: I may forget ...)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. What model would be better to use than aov? And I need to display the significans as letters, is there an other option i R to do that?

Comment: I don't think you necessarily need to change the model at all -- and probably shouldn't given the extreme imbalances. If you must use a CLD, you've got it. I'd still recommend considering other options; the pwpm display is pretty commonly used, perhaps with only the P values and means. But it is your research.